# Javafx : Disabling Menu (MenuButton) auto close

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, auto-close

I have a MenuButton that contains only CheckMenuItems. My user will usually check several items and if he has to re-open the menu for each one, he will soon throw his mouse through the screen.

I choose to use a menubutton rather than a combobox because it seems that it's not possible to put checkboxes into a combobox (https://community.oracle.com/thread/2598157).

Anyone has an idea ?
Thank you very much,
Léo

Comment: Have you tried [ControlsFX CheckedComboBox](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html) ?

Comment: It's not possible currently because I am working with java 7 and controlsFX targets java 8 (not compatible with java 7, I tryed and got a nice UnsupportedClassVersionError). Currently, it's not possible to switch my project to java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Consider in addition to the menu items to provide a toolbar with toggle buttons.

Note: [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org/DromblerFX) provides an [action framework](http://wiki.drombler.org/ActionsMenusToolbars) to keep the state and logic between menu items and toolbar buttons in sync. It supports CheckMenuItems and toggle buttons as well.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Drombler FX.

Getting Started: http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted

Blog: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/search/label/Drombler

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@FXML
public void autoShow() {

    checkmenuitem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
           e.consume();
    }
});


}
```

checkmenuitem is the id. When it is clicked, the handle method is executed. For a detailed explanation on the event.consume() method, see this:

[What is the meaning of Event consumes in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813358/what-is-the-meaning-of-event-consumes-in-javafx)

Place the above method in your controller class and then call it from the initialize method in your controller class:

```
@Override 
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    autoShow();

}
```