# What is the meaning of Event consumes in JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx

I was trying to understand [Event Handling in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJCICG) and there I found this line.

> The route can be modified as event filters and event handlers along
>   the route process the event. Also, if an event filter or event handler
>   consumes the event at any point, some nodes on the initial route might
>   not receive the event.

Can you explain what is the meaning of event consumes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Events are passed along a specific route. In most cases (e.g. mouse/key events) The route will start at the root `Node` of the `Scene` and contain every `Node` on the path from the root `Node` to the target `Node` in the scene graph. On the route to the target `Node`, event **filters** are executed and if any of those filters should consume the event, this stops any further handling of the event. Once the event has reached the target `Node` if "travels" back to the root calling any event **handler** along the way. The event handling can be stopped there too by consuming the event.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);

    StackPane root = new StackPane(rect);

    rect.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt -> {
        System.out.println("rect click(filter)");
//      evt.consume();
    });
    root.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt -> {
        System.out.println("root click(filter)");
//        evt.consume();
    });

    root.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        System.out.println("root click(handler)");
//      evt.consume();
    });
    rect.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        System.out.println("rect click(handler)");
//      evt.consume();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

If you click on `rect`, the event handling starts at the `root` `Node`. Here the filter is executed. If the event is not consumed in the filter, it is then passed to the `rect` `Node`, where the event filter receives the event. If that event is not consumed by the filter, the event handler of `rect` receives the event. If the event is not connsumed by that event handler, the event handler of the `root` `Node` receives the event.

Just uncomment some of the `evt.consume()` calls and see what happens...